# Trouble to change the distance to miles and duration in hours

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to change my distance in Miles and duration in hours format. Now distance is in kilometers and duration is in minutes so I want to change the code to change the format i.e. if duration is more than one 1 hour so it will be like 1 hour 20 minutes and distance in miles i.e. 10 miles but I'm stuck.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Fetch Distance and Time', 'mainFun')
      .addToUi();
}
function mainFun() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 8).getValues();
  Logger.log(data.length);
  for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    var startPoint = data[i][1];
    var endPoint = data[i][7];
    if(startPoint && endPoint){
      var wayPoints = [];
      for(var j=2;j<=6;j++){
        if(data[i][j]){
          wayPoints.push(data[i][j])
        }
      }
      var disMin = mapApiEndPoints(startPoint,endPoint,wayPoints)
      Logger.log(disMin)
      sheet.getRange(i+2, 9, 1, 2).setValues([disMin])
    }
  }
}
function mapApiEndPoints(startPoint,endPoint,wayPoints){
  var directions  = Maps.newDirectionFinder().setOrigin(startPoint).setDestination(endPoint);
  for (var i=0; i<wayPoints.length; i++) {
    directions.addWaypoint(wayPoints[i]);
  }
  var res = directions.getDirections();
  var time = 0; var distance = 0;
  for(var j=0; j<res.routes[0].legs.length; j++ ){
    var route = res.routes[0].legs[j];
    //Logger.log(route)
    time = time + route.duration.value;
    distance = distance + route.distance.value;
  }
  var distance = distance/1000
  var timeMin = time/60
  return [distance,timeMin];
}
```

Comment: To convert kilometers to miles, multiply by 0.62; to convert from minutes to hours divide by 60 and keep the remainder as minutes.  What specifically has you stuck here?

Comment: Thank you  for responding, I have test these thing you told me that multiply by 0.62 to get mile from kilometer but I don't want that I,m sharing a screenshot u will get that

Comment: Check this image u will understand url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbsJc.png)

Comment: "I have test these thing you told me that multiply by 0.62 to get mile from kilometer but I don't want that".  What do you mean? That is how you convert kilometers into miles. It's simple, basic math.

Comment: did you check the image

Comment: Honestly, the image didn't help. What value are you converting and its output that makes you think it is wrong? If you want to convert the duration to H hours and M minutes, have it formatted using `Utilities.formatDate`. For printing the mile, check [this](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/examples/km-mile) out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guess. Instead of this:

```
var distance = distance/1000
var timeMin = time/60
```

Try this:

```
var distance = distance/1000 * .62;
var timeMin = time/60/60;
```

Or (to get `1.23` instead of `1.23456789...`):

```
var distance = Math.round(distance/1000 * .62 * 100)/100;
var timeMin = Math.round(time/60/60 * 100)/100;
```

To get the 'XX h YY m' notation from seconds:

```js
var s = 12345;  // time in seconds
var h = Math.floor(s/3600);
var m = ('' + Math.round(s/60 % 60)).padStart(2, '0');
var time =  (h > 0) ? h + ' h ' + m  + ' min' : m + ' min';

console.log(time) // output: 3 h 26 min
```

Another approach with `Date()` object:

```js
var s = 12345;
var date = new Date(s*1000);
var timezone = date.getTimezoneOffset();
var h = date.getHours() + timezone/60; // exclude timezone offset
var m = date.getMinutes();
var time = (h>0) ? h + ' h ' + m + ' min' : m + ' min'

console.log(time); // output: 3 h 25 min
```

It gives a little different results because it doesn't round minutes properly: 350 sec -> 5 min 50 sec -> 5 min (not 6 min).

Dates and time are tricky beasts. I'm not even sure that my last example is 100% reliable for all timezones.

Comment: Great, Now the last thing is that how to implement formatting i.e. time is coming in points I need proper formatting like 1 hour 20 mint or 20 mint.

Comment: I just added the possible solution how to get hours and minutes from seconds

Comment: I have a suspicion the "divide by 1000" for distance is not correct, unless the input data is in megameters.   `time/60/60` also may be off (it's correct if the input is in seconds, but the question says it's currently in minutes.)

Comment: @DanielBeck yes, I have a suspicion that the code is a copypasted mess. :) I can only imagine what there should be.